# bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' when running a linux cmd from inside python-os.system

Tags: python, redirect, apache-kafka, echo, os.system

I want to redirect a string variable to a cmd from inside `os.system()`
in python
I am getting following error

> bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

I am using redirecting operator `<<<`

following is my implementation:-

```
my_var = "Hello World"
os.system('bash -c "linuxcmd <<< "${my_var}""')
```

Redirecting a string directly works fine; i.e

```
os.system('bash -c "linuxcmd <<< "Hello""')
```

Kindly help me with this as I am really stuck on it.

- The linux cmd that I am running here is Kafka-console producer

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right command? In bash redirect is `<<` not `<<<`.

Comment: Python has producer libraries it also supports piping rather than relying on bash features

Answer (score 1):

```
my_var = "Hello World"
os.system('bash -c "linuxcmd <<< "{}""'.format(my_var))
```

or in python3, using f-strings:

```
os.system(f'bash -c "linuxcmd <<< "{my_var}""')
```

Tested this:

```
my_var = 'test'
os.system(f'bash -c "echo {my_var}"')
```

with my python3 running on manjaro, works fine.